# TableLayout onClickListener : get Row/Column

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I have chosen to use TableLayout to draw out categories of products.

Data are fetched and rendered dynamically. I am adding both TableRow and ImageView's into it.

How can I handle `onClickListener`, when there are 3 items per TableRow?

*I cannot change the used layout, so I'm looking for solution in current situation*

Comment: How do you load your data into this table? And why can't you change the used layout? Set the 'duplicateParentState' to true on the items in your row and set a onClickListener on your row.

Comment: @Jordi I load it programmatically. Layout can't be changed for organizational reasons. You last sentence doesn't make sense for me, can you provide it please as an answer? Thanks

Comment: @MarekSebera: u want to detect clicks of elements of tablerow or the tablerow itself??

Comment: @android_hungry on items within tablerow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK , when you create dynamic rows, using a for loop:
do this:

1. use `setTag()` or `setTag(key, tag)` for each child element of table row using an increment variable
2. setonclick listener for each child element inside the for loop itself [note: **within for loop**]
3. in the `onclick(View v)` of onclicklisteners, you can detect the individual clicks by retrieving the clicked view using `v.getTag()` [convert tag to the required data type]

Answer (score 0):

Your inflated layout would have to look something like this in XML:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/somerow">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/row_item1" android:duplicateParentState="true" .... />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/row1_item2" android:duplicateParentState="true" .... />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/row1_item3" android:duplicateParentState="true" .... />
</TableRow>
```

So in java code, you should do something like this directly after inflating the row:

```
// there is some var tableRow of type TableRow
TextView myTextView = new TextView(......);
myTextView.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener); // this is the important part
myTableRow.addView(myTextView);
```

Comment: and how can I handle click on `row1_item1/2/3` with this `duplicateParentState` attribute?

Comment: I think I got your question wrong. I thought you were asking how to manage 1 clickListener on all 3 items. If you want to have a clickListener seperately:
    tableRow.findViewById(R.id.row_item1).setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener1);

or if you make your TextView dynamically, directly add the onClickListener

Comment: so you suggest adding anonymous onclicklistener to each view I'd like to handle click on?

Comment: No, I don't suggest that. I prefer to define my onClickListeners as innerclasses to make the code more clean. Sometimes, you might want to use a clickListener on multiple views which is possible by declaring them named. It's a personal thing, you can add them the way you want.

Comment: OK, can you please modify your answer to match my question, so I can accept it?